# Make function execution ONLY after the file uploading is complete. Javascript

Tags: javascript

How (by using javascript) to make function execution ONLY after the file uploading is complete? I mean 'uploading2' execute only after 'submit()' has been completed.

```
function uploadimg1() {
  document.forms.imgupload.act.value='upload';
  document.forms.imgupload.submit();
}
function uploadimg2() {
  doc = frames['frm1'].document;
  imgs=doc.getElementsByTagName('img').length-1;
  img = doc.getElementById(imgs);
  opener.document.forms[0].src.value = '<?php echo $IMGURL ?>/'+img.alt;
  window.close();
}
function uploadimg() {
  uploadimg1();
  uploadimg2();
}
```

Comment: If you are just using a normal HTML form without any additional stuff, then your only option is to have the server answers the finished upload with an HTML document that calls your JS function.